# Change a td value onchange function of select option in another td tag in same tr

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a table like

```
Header1 | Header2         | Header3        | Header 4           | Header 5
Row 1   |<span>Some Text</span>            | <select></select>
Row 2
Row 3
.
.
.
.
Rows dynamically generated.
```

Now my goal is to change the value and color of `<span>Some Text</span>` in second column on change of `<select></select>` which is in same row in header 4 column and do distinctively same for all the rows dynamically generated.

I was approaching for generating dynamic id's through jquery but not sure how this would be possible.

Tried to create a jsfiddle for better understanding of the question

http://jsfiddle.net/y8Cj3/2/

Comment: You've explained what you want, you've added a fiddle showing what you want, you haven't made any attempt to solve the problem though. You need so show you have a basic understanding of what you wish to achieve.

Comment: Do you have some control over generated html (e.g. add class )? If yes adding a class with row number would be very convenient. If no you should do some DOM traverse.

Comment: Hi @Liam. I tried to solve the problem through adding a random class in td tag and generated the id through jquery, but the problem is i lost in the middle way of implementing this and now i'm totally confused and in nowhere to go state.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it somewhat in this way (this is based on your fiddle):

```
$(".myselect").change(function() {
    var $tr = $(this).closest("tr");
    $tr.find("td:eq(1) span").css("color", "blue").text(this.value);

    // Those are columns 5 and 6
    $tr.find("td:eq(4)").text(this.value);
    $tr.find("td:eq(5)").text(this.value);
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZxNRc/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Working Demohttp://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/y8Cj3/3/

```
function changeValue(){
    $('tr td span').css('color','blue');
    $('tr:gt(0) td:nth-child(5)').text('hi');
    $('tr:gt(0) td:nth-child(6)').text('new');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[An example here](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/y8Cj3/6/)

```
$('#mySelect').on('change', function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(1).find('span')
    .text($(this).val()).css('color', 'green');
});
```

Notice `$('#mySelect')`, it's been used as the `id` of the `select` like `<select id="mySelect">`. You can use a class too, like `<select class="mySel">` and can select it using `$('.mySel')`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('change', '.theChanger', function (e) {
    console.log(e);
    var $myTR = $(this).closest('tr');
    $myTR.find('td:eq(1) span').css('color', 'blue').text('NEW TEXT');
    $myTR.find('td:eq(4)').css('color', 'orange').text('NEW TEXT');
    $myTR.find('td:eq(5)').css('color', 'orange').text('NEW TEXT')
});
```

[jsFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/y8Cj3/2/)

I used a new class of `theChanger` in the select element. I particularly used a class and not an ID because you will have multiple rows and IDs **must** be unique per page.

Answer (score 0):

No need to generate dynamic IDs (I assume you will attach this IDs to the row element - tr).

Anyhow, I've forked your fiddle and created an example of how you can change the color based on the select value (on a per row).

your row:

```
<tr>
  <td class="some-text"><span class="color-option-a">Some Text</td>
  <td>
    <select class="color-changer">
      <option value="excluded" selected="selected">Excluded</option>
        <option value="Other">Other</option>
        <option value="Alternate">Alternate</option>
        </select>
    </select>
</tr>
```

css:

```
.color-option-a {
```

color: red;

```
}
.color-option-b {
    color: green;
}
.color-option-c {
    color: blue;
}
```

jquery:

```
$('.color-changer').on('change', function(){
    var currentRow = $(this).closest('tr');
    var targetColumn = $('.some-text', currentRow);
    var targetSpan = $('span', targetColumn);

    var newColor = 'color-option-a';

    switch($(this).val()) {
        case 'Alternate':
            newColor = 'color-option-b';
            break;
        case 'Other':
            newColor = 'color-option-c';
            break;
        case 'excluded': 
           newColor = 'color-option-a'; //default
            break;         
     }
    //reset the color to none first and then apply the new one
    targetSpan.attr('class', '');
    targetSpan.addClass(newColor);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Qccba/2/

Hope it helps!